# Повторная попытка подключения DJANGO к базе данных или более продолжительная задержка запуска?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

имеется docker с базой данных Postgresql к которому цепляется Django,но возникает проблема из за скорости запуска PSQL соответственно возникает вот это:

```
web_1         |         Is the server running on host "postgresdb" (172.22.2.2) and accepting
web_1         |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

pg_1           LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Каким способом будет правильно установить задержку запуска web_1 на котором висит Django.
Или в самом Django правильнее настроить RECONNECT как вы решили данную проблему?

```
depends_on:
```

Срабатывает но база данных не успевает создать необходимые таблицы до запуска django.
Спасибо!

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'connect_timeout': 20,
        }
```

Тоже не влияет :(

Comment: `connect_timeout` - это про как долго ждать само подключение, если сеть тупит. у вас контейнер сразу репортует что бд не стартанула, поэтому в этой настройке нет смысла

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно использовать healthcheck для базы данных прямо в docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - 5432
    logging:
      driver: none
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
```

Тогда контейнер с БД будет считаться поднятым, когда пострес действительно стартанул и готов принимать запросы.

Также можно использовать команду `pg_isready` и со стороны контейнера с django, во время старта контейнера (в bash-скрипте).